# Loading an Oracle HugeBlob image into an XML image in the visual basic code-behind

Tags: xml, vb.net, oracle, image

I am trying to read an image from an Oracle table and have it as the source of an XML image, to be later printed as part of a report.  I can read the image from the data base just fine.  When I try to set it as the source of the image and then print the page, the page comes out blank.

Here's the VB code after the image is read:
(The HugeBlob is the first item retrieved by a datareader (dr2), so it is referenced as dr2.Item(0))

```vb
'Convert the HugeBlob to base64 string
Dim MyImageString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(dr2.Item(0))

'Convert the base64 string to a byte array
Dim b() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(MyImageString)

'Create a memory stream
Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream

'Load the memory stream from the byte array
MS = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)

'Create a bitmap image
Dim bmi As New BitmapImage
bmi.BeginInit()

'Load the memory stream into the bitmap image
bmi.StreamSource = MS

'Set the bitmap image as the source for the xml image
PP7.Image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill
PP7.Image.Source = bmi
```

Here's the XML Page:

```xml
<FlowDocument x:Class="PrintPreview7Image"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrintAccidentXPSForms"  
    FontFamily="Arial" 
    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
    PagePadding="0" PageWidth="816" PageHeight="1056" 
    Name="PrintPreview7Image">
    <BlockUIContainer Name="MainBlock" BreakPageBefore="True" Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <Grid Width="816">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="Image" Height="1056" Width="816"     Grid.Row="0"     Grid.Column="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>
```

Comment: The xml is the header info for the printer but I do not see any image data or a path to the image.  Where is the actual image bytes?

Comment: jdweng -  PrintPreview7Image is used as a class within the code-behind.  It is instantiated as PP7.  I suppose I could have set the image source through data binding, which I still might do after I figure out how to get the image to print.

Comment: How is Stretch connected to PrintPreview7Image. It looks like the data is empty.

Comment: It just stretches an image.  Since it was empty at that point, I assumed it would stretch an image to fill available space when an image was set for the control.

Comment: I FOUND THE ANSWER !!!!!!! (After WEEKS of struggle!)  All I had to do was to add these lines:

                            bmi.BeginInit()
                            bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
                            bmi.StreamSource = MS
                            bmi.EndInit()

after instantiating the bitmapimage.

Answer (score 0):

Although this code is for SQLServer, I thought it might be adaptable for your problem. I stole this code, probably from SO, but I can't remember so can't give proper attribution.

```
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1", connection)

connection.Open()

Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

connection.Close()

Dim picture As Image = Nothing

'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
    'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
    picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
End Using
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  IO.MemoryStream doesn't have a FromStream method.

Comment: I get the error message " 'FromStream' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' "

Comment: Try Imports System.Drawing at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE ANSWER !!!!!!! (After WEEKS of struggle!) All I had to do was to add these lines:

```
bmi.BeginInit() 
bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad 
bmi.StreamSource = MS 
bmi.EndInit()
```

after instantiating the bitmapimage